# Finding perpendicular vector on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a plane made up of vectors A, B, and J. I am trying to find a vector C where

1. BC is perpendicular to BA
2. C lies on the plane
3. BC is of length d

I believe there will always be two solutions, but I only need one.

Heres what I have tried (Im not good with inline math notation)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH1Ts.png)

I was trying to find a vector that met requirements 1 and 2, then normalize it, then scale it by d. Will this work?

EDIT: all in 3d space

Comment: I think you mean that $A,B,J$ are *points*, not vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to say that $A,B,J$ are *points*, not vectors. Note that $C$ lies on the plane iff $BC$ is orthogonal to the normal $BA \times BJ$, so taking the double cross product

$$BC := BA \times (BA \times BJ)$$

ensures that your first two conditions are satisfied. Finally, like you said, simply normalize and multiply by the required length $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've computed

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\bu}{\mathbf u}
\newcommand{\bv}{\mathbf v}
\newcommand{\bk}{\mathbf k}
\newcommand{\bn}{\mathbf n}
\bu = \frac{1}{\| B - a \|} (B - A)
\end{align}
and let
\begin{align}
\bk = \bu \times (J-A) \\
\bn = \frac{1}{\| \bk \|} bk
\end{align}
you can let
\begin{align}
\bv = \bn \times \bu
\end{align}
and $\bv$ will lie in the plane (it's orthogonal to the normal $\bn$, after all) and be 90 degrees counterclockwise from $\bu$, as see looking down at the plane as in your drawing.
That means that $d$ times $\bv$ is the vector you're looking for.